# Stylelint rule to prevent overriding a class from a library

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

One big problem with major version upgrades with breaking changes from CSS/SASS libraries is that if you happened to override the library CSS classes, your CSS overrides become a potential increased risk/scope when upgrading.

So if a CSS library exports a `.input` class, I'd like to configure a stylelint rule that will prevent me and my team from declaring an `.input` class on my CSS files.

I do understand this plugin/rule may need to be configured with a list of exported CSS classes by the library, but that's ok, we can probably create it automatically as part of the build process and pass it to the plugin.

Is there such a plugin/rule?